# Security Certificate in wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I didn't know how to add https security to my wordpress website, I just changed the http to https in the url option in General section of wordpress. Now, I'm unable to access my website, please help me solve this issue. The website is skydental.in

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an SSL certificate installed in your hosting account for the domain `skydental.in` in order to correctly use the `https` protocol. The `http` protocol is not secure and doesn't need the security authentication of an SSL certificate. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Talk to your host, buy an SSL certificate (from your host or a third party) and get it installed. Then your site will be able to use `https` and will be accessible again.

Then, use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/ to force SSL for all pages - the admin area and the front end - in a WordPress site.

*If you want to return to* `http`, see [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for recovery instructions on how to change the URLs in settings back to `http` by editing the theme's `functions.php` file or the `wp-config.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

While I am trying to access website it seems you have to setup your SSL certificate first.

Getting below message while trying to access your website

This server could not prove that it is skydental.in; its security certificate is from *.webhostbox.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

https://skydental.in/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Try to contact your hosting provider and ask them to configure SSL for you.

Now if you’re adding SSL to your existing site, then you need to setup WordPress SSL redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

You can do this by adding the following code in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.skydental.in/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```